# Is it possible to compile fmt in vs2010

Tags: c++, fmt

I know Visual studio 2010 is outdated and should not be used. I am just curious if it is possible to compile libfmt.a in vs2010?

Comment: Are you talking about [this library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)?

Comment: On [this](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) page it says that VS2015 is the first supported version.  However it does also say that you can compile version 4.x which only requires C++98.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, you are right.

Comment: @0x5453 thanks for sharing this. I will use 4.x versions for this. I don't know how I missed that when I was going through the page :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion from @0x5453, we need to use 4.x versions to build against visual studios.
Thanks